# Rails: Show or Hide elements based on DropDown selection using IF

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using an **IF Statement**, How can I hide/show an element based on the value in the **drop-down selection** (transactionType)
Here's something I've been trying
Where did I go wrong?

```
<%= form_for(transaction) do |f| %> 

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :transactionType %>
<%= f.select :transactionType, ['Income', 'Expense']%>
</div>

<%= if transaction.transactionType == 'Income' %>
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :amount %>
   <%= f.number_field :amount, options = { max: 0 }%>
   </div>
<% else %>
   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :amount %>
   <%= f.number_field :amount, options = { min: 0 }%>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using css classes..if its all about hiding elements from view...
So if you are using bootstrap,you can use hidden class.check more [**here**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes).

in below example,i have used [**ternary operator**](http://www.w3resource.com/ruby/ruby-ternary-operator.php) which is just like `if else`.
for example:-

```
   <%= form_for(transaction) do |f| %> 

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :transactionType %>
    <%= f.select :transactionType, ['Income', 'Expense']%>
   </div>
     <!--  here comes ternary operator -->    
   <div class="field <%= transaction.transactionType == 'Income' ? 'present' : 'hidden' %>">
    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <%= f.number_field :amount, options = { max: 0 }%>
   </div>
   <div class="field <%= transaction.transactionType != 'Income' ? 'present' : 'hidden' %>"">
    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <%= f.number_field :amount, options = { min: 0 }%>
   </div>
```

if **not** using bootstrap,you can create custom class to hide/show elements.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used erb in quite some time, but I think you need to change

`<%= if transaction.transactionType == 'Income' %>`

should be

`<% if transaction.transactionType == 'Income' %>`

But this is only for the initial state. After that you will need jquery to toggle according to your select element